# How to convert the vectorized text into embedding matrix using Longformer transformer

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, numpy-ndarray, huggingface-transformers

Everyone knows about converting the text into vectors and that vectors into a matrix which helps to feed the machine learning models like LightGBM as features.

```py
import transformers
from transformers import LongformerTokenizer,LongformerForSequenceClassification,Trainer, TrainingArguments, LongformerConfig,LongformerTokenizerFast
import tensorflow as tf

#tokenizer=LongformerTokenizer.from_pretrained("hf-internal-testing/tiny-random-longformer")
#model=TFLongformerForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("hf-internal-testing/tiny-random-longformer")
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
config=LongformerConfig()
test=pd.read_csv('../input/feedback-prize-effectiveness/test.csv')
train=pd.read_csv('../input/feedback-prize-effectiveness/train.csv')
# load model and tokenizer and define length of the text sequence
model = LongformerForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('allenai/longformer-base-4096',gradient_checkpointing=False,attention_window = 512)
tokenizer = LongformerTokenizerFast.from_pretrained('allenai/longformer-base-4096', max_length = 1024)
#inputs = tokenizer("Hello, my dog is cute killer and bad")
#print(inputs.input_ids)
k=[]
for i in train['discourse_text']:
    inputs=tokenizer(i)
    m=inputs.input_ids
    k.append(m)
train['long_tokens']=k
```

The above code uses the tokenization method from longformer to encode the sentences in the dataset. So, after doing that the dataset is going to look like below
[image: embeddings of the data]

So, the feature "long_tokens" should serve as a feature for the machine learning model[LightGBM].

My question is how can we transform those features to input the model?

The datatype of the "long_tokens" is tensor.

Please answer the question
Thanks & Regards
Satwik Sunnam

Comment: What type does your model need? numpy? You are also currently not using the Longformer model, which means you convert your input text just to a list of integers (not tensor). The ids were just randomly assigned during the tokenizer training and do not carry any meaning.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sentence transformers to encode sentences into vectors and then use them as features.

https://www.sbert.net/

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
model = SentenceTransformer('allenai/longformer-base-4096')

#Our sentences we like to encode
sentences = ['This framework generates embeddings for each input sentence',
    'Sentences are passed as a list of string.',
    'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.']

#Sentences are encoded by calling model.encode()
embeddings = model.encode(sentences)
```

Comment: What does the tokenizer in the Longformer do? Does that give us embeddings that resemble the sentences?